# UIScrollView taking too much time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios4

am trying to place a ScrollView in my app that has 1000,000 record, this scrollView will load when the app launches, so the app is not running until the million 1000 000 record which takes a lot of time, i was wondering is there any way to show the app and the scrollView while records are loading (show the scrollView while adding its records), below the code am using:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self loadIt];
}

- (void)loadIt{

    float startX = 0;
    float startY = 0;
    [_bigScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 312500)];
    _bigScroll.pagingEnabled = NO;
    for (counter=0; counter<999999; counter++)
    {
        UIButton *tester=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startX, startY, 10, 10)];

        if (counter % 2 == 0) {

            [tester setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        }
        else
        {

            [tester setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        }

        [_bigScroll addSubview:tester];
        [tester release];

        if (startX == 320) {
            startX = 0;
            startY += 10;
        }
        else
            startX += 10;

        NSLog(@"counter  =  %d", counter);
    }

}
```

Please advice.

Comment: Say you'll want use a collectionView, which works like a tableView and recycles a few views rather then making 10,000 views. If your not using iOs 6 take look at this lib https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView, some dude made an open source version that works for iOS4.3+.

Comment: Also simple things like keeping a variable with colour and not calling nslog may speed things up.

Comment: I would suggest..instead of loading all the records in the beginning, you can just load few records initially and then go on adding records to it as user scrolls and remove previous records, this will consume less memory.....the idea is similar to the cell reuse concept of tableView.

Comment: U must use UITableView instead of UIScrollview for such type of implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any way to show the app and the scrollView while records are loading ?

Try to use `[self performSelector:@selector(loadIt) withObject:nil]; or
    [self performSelector:@selector(loadIt) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];`


It will not block your UI until the execution of this method.

You are loading lots of records. Actually you should not load all records at at time. You should use mechanism something like tableview is using i.e.load only those record which are in visible area of scrollview. Don't load new rows until the scroll and you should reuse row or views so speedup the scrolling.

Comment: U ROCK, I GOT UR IDEA AND THATS WHAT AM HEADING TO DO :)

Comment: do u have any simple way to scroll others when scroll ends?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: All you're achieving here is blocking your UI thread with a long operation later on - which will also result in poor user-experience.

Comment: then whats ur solution? tableview cant be applied in my case, i need scroll view cuz am showing in each row 32 separated button of size 10x10, wats ur advice?

Comment: I am not saying tableview suit to your requirement. but there are lots of custom scrollviews are available and you can customize easily. I have taken tableview as an example to express concept of reusability and and how to decrease loading time.

Comment: If it is fixed like your each row has fixed X buttons then you can use tableview easily. Just create simple cell with "X" number of buttons. And with little take care of reusable identifier and some basic stuffs and tableview will do almost everything for your

Comment: " i need scroll view cuz am showing in each row 32 separated button of size 10x10, wats ur advice?" My advice would be, redesign your app, this sounds like a usability disaster.

Comment: As I have suggested you can use tableview and each row will have 32 buttons. So, obviously row will have much height. I can't suggest much without seeing your current design.

Comment: @lducool to add to this, a `UITableView` with custom cells that contain the ten buttons.

Comment: @jrturton probably a very crashy disaster too when run on a real device - especially one that can run iOS4.

Comment: @lducool I've just noticed the iOS4 tag on the question (really?!), so no doubt some of this support is absent from `UITableView`

Comment: @Marko: I am not sure you are talking about which supports. In my answer I have not suggested tableview I have taken as an example to explain concept of re usability and basic stuffs. Still we can do this by table view with just simple custom cell. Read my above comments.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) for `UIScrollView` is very clear that the scrolled view should be tiled, with your application providing tiles as the view scrolls.

*The object that manages the drawing of content displayed in a scroll view should tile the content’s subviews so that no view exceeds the size of the screen. As users scroll in the scroll view, this object should add and remove subviews as necessary.*

This is necessary both for performance and memory usage:  the scrollable view is backed by a `CALayer`, which in turn is backed by a bitmap.   The same is true for each of the `UIButton` objects created.

Whilst it is not surprising that this takes a long time,  it's more of a mystery that your app hasn't been terminated for using too much memory.

Both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` are examples of views that tile their content. You may find you can use one of these to implement you requirements, and if not, follow the model they use.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create 1000,000 views . You can create views dynamically and  remove the previous views those are not visible at the screen space. So at the time of scrolling you can create new views and remove the views those are out of visible area of screen.
This will help you to save memory otherwise whether you are using ARC in your project if you load that much number of views in memory there will surely a chance of crash , ARC will not help you in that case.

Answer (score 0):

once try this Change the code in the

```
-viewdidload()
{
    [self loadIt];//change this to 
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadIt) withObject:nil];
}
```

Comment: btw: that should be `-(void) viewDidLoad()`